# Multiple-level join condition in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm struggling to set a condition on a multiple-level join in my Rails ActiveRecord query:

```ruby
class CourseSlot < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :user, through: :course
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
end
```

The HABTM association is stored in a `CoursesUsers` table:

```ruby
create_table "courses_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "user_id", null: false
  t.bigint "course_id", null: false
end
```

I want to query for any slot whose users include the current user. I tried:

```ruby
current = User.find(current_user_id)
CourseSlot
  .joins(course: :users)
  .where(course: {users: current})
```

But this gives me an error:

```ruby
SELECT  "course_slots".* 
FROM "course_slots" 
INNER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."id" = "course_slots"."course_id"
INNER JOIN "courses_users" ON 
  "courses_users"."course_id" = "courses"."id" 
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "courses_users"."user_id" 
WHERE "course"."user_id" = 2 
ORDER BY "course_slots"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
*** ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::UndefinedTable: 
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "course"
```

I can see that the query is missing a `FROM` clause, but I've struggled in vain to find a way to get ActiveRecord to generate the right query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code like below

```
CourseSlot.joins(course: :users).where(courses: { users: { id: current_user_id } })
```

In your query table name is used as 'course' but i think it should be `courses`

`WHERE "course"."user_id" = 2`

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I don't follow, I'm afraid. I'm referencing the ActiveRecord association names in the query. The association from `CourseSlot` to `Course` is a `belongs_to`, so it's the singular `course`. The association from `Course` to `User` is the plural `users` because it's HABTM. So there is no `user_id` on a `Course`.

Comment: But, this did put me on the right track - thanks @ganesh-navale. The final answer was ` CourseSlot.joins(course: :users).where(courses: {users: {id: current_user_id}})`